# Content for Registered User on Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am working with Joomla 2.5 and I need to set a page each language to be visible only to registered users.

Now that's what I have done already:

1. I created 5 new pages with restricted access (Registered), one each language
2. Created 5 new menu items, linking to single articles with restricted access (Registered)
3. Created a module to display the above menu with restricted access (Registered)

Everything works fine, so the menu items link to the correct pages, except that I get the module also for Public users.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a guest usergroup which is not a part of the registered user group. Then you should set your default usergroup for not-logged in users as guest instead of public. You can do that in the options of the user manager page. That should do the trick.

Comment: Guest user group how to - http://www.cmsmind.com/joomla-1-7-5-easy-steps-to-create-guest-only-access-to-menus-and-modules/

Comment: Got it and it was easy the how to by Brent!